# Merging and sorting queue/list implementation

Tags: java, queue, kotlin

My requirement is implementing a `Queue<T>` (where `T` is a `Lexeme`) that is capable of insertion sort and insertion merge.

The `Lexeme` interface:

```kotlin
/**
 * A lexeme is the smallest piece of data it is possible to
 * extract during the lexing process.
 * For example, a lexeme could be a keyword, a comment, or an identifier.
 *
 * @author Edoardo Luppi
 */
interface Lexeme : Segment {
  /** The IntelliJ Platform type for this lexeme. */
  fun getPlatformType(): IElementType

  /** The start offset for this lexeme inside the characters buffer. */
  override fun getStartOffset(): Int

  /** The end offset for this lexeme inside the characters buffer. */
  override fun getEndOffset(): Int

  /** Returns if this lexeme fully contains the inputted lexeme or not. */
  fun contains(lexeme: Lexeme): Boolean

  /** Returns if this lexeme intersects with the inputted lexeme or not. */
  fun intersects(lexeme: Lexeme): Boolean

  /**
   * Creates a copy of this lexeme, shifted right (using a positive number)
   * or left (using a negative number) by the given positions.
   */
  fun shift(positions: Int): Lexeme

  /** Creates a copy of this lexeme with different offsets. */
  fun copy(startOffset: Int, endOffset: Int): Lexeme
}
```

**What do I mean by insertion merge?**

During the lexing process of a document, the document is lexed with multiple passes, and each pass detects some types of tokens. A pass' token may overlap with the preceding one on the same offsets, in which case the latest token always wins.

[image]

In the end I came up with something pretty straightforward using an `ArrayList` as base implementation.
The following is the important part:

```kotlin
/**
 * A queue implementation that sort lexemes on insertion and that
 * is capable of merging new ones with old ones in case they overlap.
 *
 * @author Edoardo Luppi
 */
class SortedArrayLexemeQueue(initialCapacity: Int = 32) :
    ArrayList<Lexeme>(initialCapacity),
    Queue<Lexeme> {
  override fun add(element: Lexeme): Boolean {
    if (isEmpty()) {
      return super.add(element)
    }

    val index = findIndex(element)

    if (index < 0) {
      // The new element does not overlap with other elements,
      // thus we can use the index returned by 'findIndex'
      // to insert it on the right spot and keep the queue sorted
      super.add(-index - 1, element)
      return true
    }

    val iterator = listIterator(index)

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      val lexeme = iterator.next()

      if (!element.intersects(lexeme)) {
        continue
      }

      iterator.remove()

      if (element.contains(lexeme) && iterator.hasNext()) {
        // The new element fully override the old one, so we simply remove it
        continue
      }

      if (lexeme.startOffset < element.startOffset) {
        iterator.add(lexeme.copy(lexeme.startOffset, element.startOffset))
      }

      iterator.add(element)

      if (lexeme.endOffset > element.endOffset) {
        iterator.add(lexeme.copy(element.endOffset, lexeme.endOffset))
      }
    }

    return true
  }

  /**
   * Returns the index where we should start processing overlaps for this element.
   * Otherwise, if the element does not overlap with existing ones, returns
   * the inverted insertion point (-insertion point - 1), defined as the index
   * at which the element should be inserted so that the list remains sorted.
   */
  private fun findIndex(element: Lexeme): Int {
    var sortedPosition = size

    for ((index, lexeme) in withIndex()) {
      if (element.intersects(lexeme)) {
        return index
      }

      if (lexeme.startOffset > element.startOffset) {
        sortedPosition = index
        break
      }
    }

    return -sortedPosition - 1
  }

  ...
```

The expected queue size is around 10-60 elements, as it gets consumed often.
Because of the merge feature, I could not use the standard `PriorityQueue`.

My question is, can I do this better (considering I have a small amount of time)? If so, how?
Do you spot any possible issue?

Answer (score 1):

A couple improvements I've made, plus I bug I didn't notice.

To ease lexeme's offsets retrieval, we provide destructuring capability:

```kotlin
interface Lexeme {
  ...

  // Provide destructuring capability
  operator fun component1(): Int = getStartOffset()
  operator fun component2(): Int = getEndOffset()
}
```

We can optimize the insertion when the inserted lexeme's start offset is greater or equal to the last lexeme's end offset, as it means there are no overlaps and it's already sorted:

```kotlin
override fun add(element: Lexeme): Boolean {
  val (elementStart, elementEnd) = element

  if (isEmpty() || elementStart >= last().getEndOffset()) {
    return super.add(element)
  }

  ...
```

And finally, inside the `ListIterator<Lexeme>` loop, we need to check if the new element has already been added, as we don't want it to be added each iteration (see the `elementAdded` boolean variable):

```kotlin
val iterator = listIterator(index)
var elementAdded = false

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  val lexeme = iterator.next()

  if (!element.intersects(lexeme)) {
    continue
  }

  iterator.remove()

  if (element.contains(lexeme) && iterator.hasNext()) {
    // The new element fully override the old one, so we simply remove it
    continue
  }

  val (lexemeStart, lexemeEnd) = lexeme

  if (lexemeStart < elementStart) {
    iterator.add(lexeme.copy(lexemeStart, elementStart))
  }

  if (!elementAdded) {
    iterator.add(element)
    elementAdded = true
  }

  if (lexemeEnd > elementEnd) {
    iterator.add(lexeme.copy(elementEnd, lexemeEnd))
  }
}
```

Comment: Since no one else has answer the question yet, you can actually edit the original question and make improvements.